# Почему не добавляется инфо в БД из формы?

Tags: php, mysql

Я очень новичок в **php**, опыт где-то недели в бэкенде и надеюсь мне не кинут помидоры, а помогут.

Вопрос почему не добавляется инфо в базу данных при клике на кнопку формы? Вроде все делаю правильно.

**Php** код

```
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
        $Dino_name = $_POST["Dinosaur_name"];
        $Height = $_POST["Height"];
        $Weight = $_POST["Weight"];

        $Connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root",""); //подключаемся к базе данных
        $Selected = mysqli_select_db($Connection,"new"); // выбираем из базы данных

        $Query = "INSERT INTO `dinosaurs`(`dinosaur_name`,`height`,`weight`)
                VALUES('$Dino_name','$Height','$Weight')";

                $execute = mysqli_query($Query);
    }
```

**HTML** форма

```
<form action="simple.php">
        <fieldset>
            Dinosaur:<br><input type="text" name="Dinosaur_name" value=""><br>
            Height:<br><input type="text" name="Height" value=""><br>
            Weight:<br><input type="text" name="Weight" value=""><br>
            <br><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit youre record"><br>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

И [**картинка**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv3Bb.jpg) для ясности

Comment: `form` по дифолту `GET` отправляет, добавьте `<form method="POST" action="simple.php"`

Comment: @KostaB. сработало спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form` по дифолту `GET` отправляет, добавьте `<form method="POST" action="simple.php"`